# Access denied on EnumProcessModules - C++

Tags: c++, winapi, access-denied

I am trying to list all modules on a specific process, but I am getting "Access denied", even when I set token privileges.
Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "cmcfg32.lib")

BOOL SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege) 
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilege, &luid))
    {
        char buf[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 255, NULL);
        cout << "LookupPrivilegeValue error: " << buf;   
        return FALSE; 
    }
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege) { tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; }
    else { tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0; }

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, (PDWORD)NULL))
    { 
        char buf[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 255, NULL);
        cout << "AdjustTokenPrivileges error: " << buf;   
        return FALSE; 
    } 
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
    {
        printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
        return FALSE;
    } 
    return TRUE;
}

int GetPID(char pname[])
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = NULL;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0); 
    Process32First(hSnapshot,&pEntry);
    do { if(strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, pname) == 0) { return pEntry.th32ProcessID; } } while(Process32Next(hSnapshot,&pEntry));
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE currentToken;
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &currentToken);
    if (!SetPrivilege(currentToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Unable to adjust privileges", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    DWORD ID = GetPID("test.exe");
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, ID);
    if(!hProcess)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Process not found", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        HMODULE hMods[2048];
        DWORD cbNeeded;
        if(EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (cbNeeded/sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
            {
                TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
                if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName)/sizeof(TCHAR)))
                {
                    cout << "DLL: " << szModName << " Handle: " << hMods[i] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            char buf[256];
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 255, NULL);
            cout << "Error: " << buf;
        }    
        system("pause");
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I can list process modules of any other process, but I can't with a specific one.
Both process are running with the same user credentials.

Can you tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What process is it?  Maybe it has a driver component "protecting" it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see the Security of kernel objects you are interested in. May be the target process has set its owner/DACL information such that it disallows READ for other processes. AntiVirus programs, services, file-system/kernel-driver are such kind of processes denying such actions.

And more importantly: it depends on the elevation/admin/ring-level of your own process.

ADDED:
Privileges doesn't directly apply to objects, but to the system as a whole. Try opening with `TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS` and see if it succeeds.

Comment: I tried opening with TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, without success. I also checked  the processes privileges, and both process are with SeDebugPrivilege enabled. Is that a problem?
EDIT: I disabled SeDebugPrivilege in the process that I am trying to access, and still had no success.

Comment: I already mentioned some kernel objects may have been protected explicitly, so that they cannot be accessed at all.